# No Audience Targeting Option

Tags: 2007, audience-targeting

I wrote a web part that pretty much just grabs info from an announcements list on one site, and redisplays it on another. Everything pretty much works fine except when I edit the web part, in the properties panel, I don't have the option for audience targeting. Which sucks, because I need to target this web part.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Note:SharePoint 2007, Visual Studio 2010, WSPBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reproducing this web part using a Data View Web Part in SharePoint Designer 2007? I believe DVWPs have Target Audience capability.

Comment: I did try that, but I wasn't able to display/filter the announcements the way I needed to. Probably just because I'm no good at using the designer. Took me less time to just write a quick web part! :)

Comment: Yeah, in order to use the DVWP in this way, you'd need to modify the XSLT in the code view so it produces the XHTML markup that you require for the layout. I wrote a blog post on producing a simlar view a short while ago, if you want to have a look: http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.com/2010/03/sharepoint-designer-dataview-web-parts.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you put audience targeting on the list that you're consuming instead? I'm not sure if the targeting would flow down to the web part but maybe worth a shot.